# How to store volume of product in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am wondering how to store volume data in my database (volume of a bottle). Currently my table is set up like this.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LookupSize]
(
    [idSize] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Size] [nchar](50) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_LookupSize] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
)
```

I have the stored looking like this

```
1 12oz-355ml
2 12.5oz-375ml
3 12.9oz-382ml
4 10oz-296ml
5 11oz-330ml
etc
```

How can I sort this data as it is, or is there a better way of structuring the table. I use this as a lookup table. Right now it sorts with the decimal coming before the whole number.

```
ID  Size                                        
3   10oz-296ml                                        
15  11.5oz-340ml                                      
13  11oz-330ml                                        
18  12.5oz-375ml                                      
1022    12.9oz-382ml                                      
4   12oz-355ml                                        
1020    13.5oz-400ml
```

This is the query I am using

```
SELECT        
    idSize, Size
FROM            
    LookupSize
ORDER BY 
    Size ASC
```

How do I sort it to achieve this result?

```
ID Size                                     
3   10oz-296ml                                        
13  11oz-330ml  
15  11.5oz-340ml                                      
18  12.5oz-375ml

4       12oz-355ml

1022    12.9oz-382ml                                      
1020    13.5oz-400ml
```

Thank you for any assistance

Comment: Can't you create a column `OnceSize` and a computed column `MLSize AS OnceSize * 29.574`? Then select from your table and order by `OnceSize ASC`.

Comment: I agree with @Sami. Two new columns, say `Ounces` and `Milliliters`, even if they're parsed from the text you already have, will give you much more flexibility in the long run than trying to do the parsing on a query by query basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two data values in the Size column. You should split that up into two columns. This will fix the sorting problem.

Now, if you want to stick to the existing database structure, you can use an expression and sort by that expression. The performance will be affected in case of large data sets with this approach.

```
SELECT        
 idSize, Size, SUBSTRING([Size], CHARINDEX('-', [Size]) + 1, 50) AS mlSize
FROM            
 LookupSize
ORDER BY 
 mlSize ASC
```

Comment: This did the trick. I wasn't sure how to achieve this. Thank you